# Wordpress post creation option from menu

Tags: wordpress

I have started using wordpress to create a website for my students. I have created users with *contributor* priviledges, so that they can write their own thoughts & submit them for moderation in the blog, but I don't want them to touch or get in the dashboard area.

I have tried *Sidebar Login* plugin which seems fit for my purpose, but it has some bug, which does not let it work as it suppose to. There was also no response from the developer regarding the problem.

Then I tried *Press This* tool in wordpress (Open Press This button) which seems perfect for my requirement, but I have no idea how to put *Open Press This* button in the menu bar in my site or at least to any of the pages.

Can anyone suggest a way out from the situation?